# Is there a way in Kotlin to ensure that a generic type that inherits a interface still is a interface or to assume that it would be?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to declare a function with a generic type which has to inherit from another generic type that should be an interface, and some other class.
But Kotlin complains and doesn't let me do this.

```
class SomeClass<T: SomeInterface> {

    fun <R>someFunktion(task: R) where  R : SomeOtherClass, R : T {}
}
```

If I just replace the generic type `T` in the function declaration with `SomeInterface`, it works.

```
class SomeClass<T: SomeInterface> {

    fun <R>someFunktion(task: R) where  R : SomeOtherClass, R : SomeInterface {}
}
```

So it seems the problem is that Kotlin does not know whether `T` is an interface or a class. If it would be a class it could not work because Kotlin does not support multi inheritance for classes.
So does someone know a solution? Thank you already in advance for every effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your above code example results in the Kotlin compiler to complain:

> Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter

It says that you cannot have your variable `R` be bound by a second type parameter `T`. However, for whatever reason, the problem can just be suppressed: If you add the annotation

```
@Suppress("BOUNDS_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BOUNDED_BY_TYPE_PARAMETER")
fun <R>someFunktion(task: R) where  R : SomeOtherClass, R : T {}
```

then Kotlin will stop complaining and everything works just fine.